# SBT IVY Issue - Error: Could not find or load main class Realm

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt, teamcity, ivy

In a project using **Play Framework (2.10:2:1.1)** build a distribution zip using **play dist**.

Under the covers it is using **SBT (0.12.2)**

It has been running fine but i noticed it was running against **java 1.6** as this was in the path of the build server. I changed this to **1.7** and started to get this error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Realm -Dsbt.boot.host='artifactoryhostname' -Dsbt.boot.user='someUser' -Dsbt.boot.password='pw'  -jar D:\Dev\MP\external_software\sbt\0.12.2\sbt-launch.jar clean
```

I reverted the Env Variables back to put 1.6 on the path again but this has not reverted the problem.

I have searched for anyone else with the same error thinking it must be common to IVY SBT but I have found nothing.

I know nothing of the SBT ecosystem or IVY all other builds are Maven and they work just fine.

Anyone have any clues? Why 'Realm'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was not an issue with the **Path** but with **Java_Home**. Team city had been running under a different account that had a different setting for **Java_Home**.

I rebooted the Team City server to make it aware of the changes I had deliberately made to **Path** in doing so it picked up the different and incompatible settings for **Java_Home**.

Reverting back the **path** made no difference as I was always restarting the Team City Server.

**Conclusions:**

1) use Build Parameters tab in Team City to check its view of the world in the working and none working start. Team City is a fantastic application and presents the global view of all parameters per build.

2) **SBT (0.12.2) needs Java_Home to be = Java 1.6** or at least something in our customisation does.

3) Don't forget to restart the TC Agent to get the latest Env Variables. Team city appears to disconnect it but not restart it (which is fair enough)